# pandas replace null values for a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with many columns, say:

```
df:
name   salary  age   title
John      100   35    eng
Bill      200  NaN    adm
Lena      NaN   28    NaN
Jane      120   45    eng
```

I want to replace the null values in salary and age, but no in the other columns. I know I can do something like this:

```
u = df[['salary', 'age']]
df[['salary', 'age']] = u.fillna(-1)
```

But this seems terse as it involves copying. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```py
subset = ['salary', 'age']
df.loc[:, subset] = df.loc[:, subset].fillna(-1)
```

Comment: Thanks to @piRSquared's answer, here's the final answer I was looking for:

    df.loc[:, ['salary', 'age']].fillna(-1, inplace=True)

Comment: inplace=True does not work on sub-slices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377263/pandas-fillna-method-does-not-work-inplace

Comment: This does not work anymore. However `df.loc[:, ['salary', 'age']] = df.loc[:, ['salary', 'age']].fillna(-1)` does.

Comment: @FrancisSmart see Cheng's comment above yours.  It refers to the same thing.

Comment: @piRSquared Just trying to make the answer a little more accessible.

Answer (score 27):

[According to Pandas documentation in 23.3](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
values = {'salary': -1, 'age': -1}
df.fillna(value=values, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

It is not so beautiful, but it works:

```
df.salary.fillna(-1, inplace=True)
df.age.fillna(-1, inplace=True)
df
>>>    name  salary   age title
    0  John   101.0  35.0   eng
    1  Bill   200.0  -1.0   adm
    2  Lena    -1.0  28.0   NaN
    3  Jane   120.0  45.0   eng
```

Comment: This was the only approach that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was hoping fillna() had subset parameter like drop(), maybe should post request to pandas however this is the cleanest version in my opinion.

```
df[["salary", "age"]] = df[["salary", "age"]].fillna(-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df = df.assign(
    salary=df.salary.fillna(-1),
    age=df.age.fillna(-1),
)
```

if you want to chain it with other operations.