# pandas replace null values for a subset of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas dataframe, I want to replace nan values by a zero if values in an other column are not nan.
I tried to adapt the answer from this question: [pandas replace null values for a subset of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191893/pandas-replace-null-values-for-a-subset-of-columns)

However, the nan values are not replaced (see code below). What did I do wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
df.loc[df['Litho'].notnull(),'Mu_alt'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.loc[df['Litho'].notnull(),'Mu_alt']
>>>0      NaN
>>>1      NaN
>>>2      NaN
>>>3      NaN
>>>4      NaN
>>>5      NaN
>>>6      NaN
>>>7      NaN
```

If I replace `df['Litho'].notnull()` by `:` in the first line, the nan values are replaced by a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign back replaced values for avoid [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments/21463854#21463854):

```
m = df['Litho'].notnull()
df.loc[m,'Mu_alt'] = df.loc[m,'Mu_alt'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: will there not be an easy way around like if  `df.col2.notna` and col1 is na then simply zerp the col1 values, Just thinking loud :)